# ggplot geom_line in polar coordinates connects strangely

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

I want to plot `r = theta` from 0 to 20\pi, which should be a spiral with ten loops.

This works ok:

```
data.frame(x=seq(0,20*pi, length.out=1000)) %>% mutate(theta=x %% (2*pi), r=x) %>% 
ggplot() + aes(x=theta, y=r) + coord_polar(start=-pi/2, direction=-1) + 
ggtitle("r=theta") + geom_line() + ylim(0,20*pi) + xlim(0, 2*pi)
```

[image: With points]

But when I change the `geom_point` to `geom_line`, it connects the points strangely:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: adding `%>% #arrange(r) %>%` and `+ geom_path()` gets you part of the way there, but the `geom_path` wont cross the `0` line. Puzzling...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing to do is to set the `group` aesthetic to stop the lines doubling back with `geom_path`. Here I set things up slightly differently to avoid a gap at theta = 0

```
data.frame(theta = rep(seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 100), 10)) %>% 
  mutate(r = seq(0, 20 * pi, length = 1000), z = rep(1:10, each = 100)) %>%   
  ggplot() + aes(x=theta, y=r, group = z) + 
  coord_polar(start = -pi/2, direction = -1) + 
  ggtitle("r = theta") + 
  geom_path() + 
  ylim(0, 20 * pi) + xlim(0, 2 * pi)
```

Comment: So the trick is to group by mod 2 pi, and duplicate the points that fall on edge into each group. Annoying but it works.